# Upper bound wildcard in Java Generics

Tags: java, generics, exception

after searched for a while I still couldn't find any answer to my question, even there's couple of Generics related topic, so here you go:

```
ArrayList<? super IOException> list = new ArrayList<Exception>();
list.add(new FileNotFoundException("this is ok."));
list.add(new IOException("This is ok"));
list.add(new ClassCastException("compile err"));//why compile err?
list.add(new Exception("compile err"));//why compile err?
```

Why last two line doesn't compile? Especially the last line. I've been doing quite a bit test on this topic but still couldn't catch the logic.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ArrayList<? super IOException>` could be any of the following (since there is a wild card):

```
ArrayList<IOException>
ArrayList<Exception>
ArrayList<Throwable>
ArrayList<Object>
```

The code needs to work with all four possibilities.

But if it is an `ArrayList<IOException>`, you cannot put in a `ClassCastException` or an `Exception`, hence the compile errors.

> Here's what I don't get: why this one compile------>>> list.add(new FileNotFoundException("this is ok.")); <<<----I think FileNotFoundException also below the bound of IOException. but it compiles fine.

No, FileNotFoundException is fine, because it extends IOException and you can put it in all of the four types of lists.

Note that for historical reasons, arrays do not get the same strict type checking, you can compile the following (and then get an array store exception at runtime):

```
   Exception[] a = new IOException[4];
   a[0] = new FileNotFoundException("this is ok.");  
   a[1] = new IOException("This is ok");
   a[2] = new ClassCastException("compiles, but boom!");
   a[3] = new Exception("compiles, but boom!");
```

Comment: Thank you, also Tom, here's what I don't get: why this one compile------>>> list.add(new FileNotFoundException("this is ok.")); <<<----I think FileNotFoundException also below the bound of IOException. but it compiles fine.

Comment: After a while of digest, finally got the idea:) even after line1, list = new ArrayList<Exception>(), but the list's elements' base class types are still be restricted within classes that satisfied with condition "? super IOException",in another word, the base class of the element need to be at least(or sub-class of) IOException.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the same declaration of `list`, but with a different assignment:

```
ArrayList<? super IOException> list = new ArrayList<IOException>();
```

No change in the type of `list`, but now adding a `ClassCastException` or `Exception` is clearly wrong.

Comment: Could you be more specific? more detail please, I think you the one who understand the core of my question, so please give some more detail.

Comment: @Kai What don't you get? That it's the type of the reference that matters? Or that you shouldn't be able to add an `Exception` to `ArrayList<IOException>`? Or that there may, in general, be another reference to the `ArrayList` with different (but correct) bounds?

Comment: or could anyone extend this answer in more detail please, some example?

Comment: thanks Tom, here's what I don't get: why this one compiles fine------>>> list.add(new FileNotFoundException("this is ok.")); <<<----I think FileNotFoundException also below the bound of IOException. but it compiles fine.

Comment: I thought start from line2, I'm dealing with the 'list' which is type: "ArrayList<Exception>" hence the above questions.

Answer (score 1):

`Exception` is the superclass as [`IOException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html) **extends** [`Exception`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html). You could use:

```
 List<Exception> list = new ArrayList<Exception>();
 list.add(...); // any exception
```

Then it will compile for all exception types.

Comment: yes, i know, but still I need to understand the reason for the question. anyway thanX:)

Comment: sorry, but this doesn't answer my question yet:(.

Comment: I mean given the validity of the first line(the definition of the list was valid), and what's the logic for compiler to fail the last two line?

Answer (score 1):

To me this refers to lower boundend Wildcards: `<? super IOException>`. Upper bounded wildcards would be `<? extends IOException>`.

The wildcard in your example seems effective only in the line the new `Object` is assigned to the variable. When later accessed, it is obviously no longer effective. It is then just the same as `ArrayList<IOException>`.

So your explanation to yourself is apparently wrong. Upper bounded and lower bounded means what it says.

Answer (score 0):

i think because the last to exceptions aren't derived from the base class IOException

Comment: I thought exactly the opposite: since 'super' indicate that any class that "IOException based-on" should be valid, e.g. 'Exception', or 'Object'. But seems this is only true for the first line, but not for the rest, still out of logic X-(.

Answer (score 0):

As per your ArrayList reference generic declaration, You can only add actual IOException (Because of ? super) or the objects which extends IOException in to the list.

ClassCaseException and Exception are not derived from IOException, so it fails.